# JQuery - Trouble with .css('display') property

Tags: jquery, css

```
// CSS
#popupUser{width:180px; height:180px; position:absolute; background:#FFFFFF; border:#000000 2px solid; display:none;}
.viewUser{width:173px; float:left; padding:10px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:20px; border:#000000 1px solid;}    

// HTML + Jquery
<body>  
    <div class="contenitore">   
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {      
                $(".viewUser")
                    .mousemove(function (e) {
                        if($("#popupUser").css('display')=='none') {
                $("#popupUser").css({left:e.pageX+15, top:e.pageY -190}).show();
                            alert("None");
                        }
                    })
                    .mouseout(function () {
                    $("#popupUser").hide();
                });         
            });
        </script>      

        <div class="viewUser">
            Content
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div id="popupUser">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

What i'd like to aspect is that, when i go on the div **viewUser** with the mouse, the alert is showed (printing *none*). After this, until I'll left that div, I must never seen another alert (because the *display* property, when I call the .show() function, should be setted as *block*).

But that's not happens : in fact some time (when I still moving on the **viewUser** with the mouse) I see the alert. Why this behaviour?

Cheers

**UPDATE**

In fact what i'd like to do is this : when i go on the mouse in the **viewUser** div, i'll do an ajax call to the server to get some info and append it to **popupUser**. So, i won't to call this ajax call everytime i move the mouse on the div :)

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Google Chrome 8.0.xxxxxx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when the popup appears and the mouse is on it, the mouseout of the `.viewUser` fires and closes it again..

If you want to track the element then reposition it in relation to the mouse.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $(".viewUser")
                .mousemove(function (e) {
                    var $popU = $("#popupUser");
                    if($popU.css('display')=='none') {
                        $popU.show();
                    }
                    $popU.css({left:e.clientX+2, top: e.clientY-2});
                })
                .mouseout(function () {
                $("#popupUser").hide();
            });         
        });
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/RQhTp/

---

The solution (*after comments*) is to use a timeout for the mouseout so that the div has enough time to re-position itself..

```
        $(document).ready(function() {      
            $(".viewUser")
                .mouseenter(function(e){
                    $("#popupUser").show().css({left:e.clientX+1, top: e.clientY+1});
                     clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
                })
                .mousemove(function (e) {
                    $("#popupUser").css({left:e.clientX+1, top: e.clientY+1});
                })
                .mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).data('timeout', setTimeout(function(){
                        $("#popupUser").hide();
                    }, 100));

            });         
        });
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/RQhTp/3/

Comment: Yes, but if you looks at your example, the popup is not so "fluid". Seems that sometimes it disappair :) Check for example this : http://jsfiddle.net/yEeyV/ is totally fluid

Comment: @markzzz, the alert also forces you to move the mouse and the `mouseout` event occurs ..

Comment: @markzzz, the example you show has a large offset to the popup. The point is that when you move the mouse fast, you enter the `#popupUser` and that causes the mouseout from the `.viewUser` so it closes, and when it closes you are over the `.viewUser` so it opens again..  i will post a solution..

Comment: hehhe you are right. In fact if i move right to the left is total fluid! I waiting your solution. thanks for your help!!!

Comment: In fact seems working. But is not so clear how it can works. I'll try to check it out...

Comment: Last example is less fluid then other. What i don't understand is : `1)` why if i put the popup far away from the pointer (like `$("#popupUser").css({left:e.pageX+15, top:e.pageY -190})`, where i can't go on this div) the mouseout is called; `2)` that timeout logic :)

Answer (score 1):

You need `.mouseover()` and not `.mousemove()` - mousemove enables you to track every single movement of the mouse within that element; mouseover is just for the initial mouse contact.

Comment: Now, i need mousemove(), because i want to display some div belongs the mouse :)